# In Overlord, how does Nazarick get food?

Tags: overlord

I know that it isn't very relevant to the plot, but a few times we find out just how much and how luxurious the food is at Nazarick. How do they get it? In the new world, do they grow and farm it, or do they buy it? If they buy it, how so since they aren't getting it from the outside human world?

Comment: At one point Demiurge asks if he can go buy grain before heading back to Nazarick. If I remember correctly, we also find out that Nazarick has an apple orchard tended to by a Dryade. I'm guessing that it's most likely that most of Nazarick is sustained by food grown in Nazarick.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely magic in some form or another, supplemented by growing, buying, and/or slaughtering.

In Volume 8 Side 2, we find out that Ainz is providing food for the Lizardmen until the fish farms could grow. "The food Cocytus had given them was made with a magic item called Dagda’s Cauldron." The population of Lizardmen after the war was closing in on 1,000. They already had some food of their own. I'd say that the single magic item was feeding about 500+ lizardmen. Considering that Nazarick had an obscene amount of every resource you can imagine, I'd say that magic, in one form or another, was providing the food. Maybe it was items, maybe it was auto generated by the facilities similar to pop monsters and basic repairs automatically done, or maybe it was something else. Either way, I don't think they really had to worry about buying it.

We also find out at some point that the dryads are helping with growing stuff, fruit I think. At some point the bar tender mentions he's using some of that newly grown fruit in an alcoholic beverage. (Sorry, I can't remember the sources for those.)

It's also worth noting that despite their large population, Nazarick doesn't need much food.

"Thanks to certain items, most of the NPCs no longer needed to eat or drink."